# Magento 2 - "Undefined constant 'Product\SizeChart\Helper\Data'" while using helper

Tags: magento2, helper, factory, magento2.3.5-p1

If anyone have idea then please share with me.

I am going to stuck in this error:

> Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'Product\SizeChart\Helper\Data' in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/app/code/Product/SizeChart/view/frontend/templates/size.phtml:48
> Stack trace: #0
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):
> include() #1
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Product\SizeChart\Block\Display),
> '/opt/lampp/htdo...', Array) #2
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render',
> Array) #3
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Product\SizeChart\Block\Display),
> '/opt/lampp/htdo...', Array) #4
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php(26):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\ in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/M2/app/code/Product/SizeChart/view/frontend/templates/size.phtml
> on line 48

here is my helper code:

```
<?php namespace Product\SizeChart\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Product\SizeChart\Model\CurdFactory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $curdFactory;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CurdFactory $curdFactory,
        $data = []
    )     {
        $this->curdFactory = $curdFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->curdFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: please check my answer and update me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below line in your helper class after `namespace` line, I think you're using `Context` anywhere in your constructor and there you only used **Context $context** and that context file is not available with your Helper file's location here `Product\SizeChart\Helper\Context`. So you can define that file's path like below..

```
namespace Product\SizeChart\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any issue with your code then just kindly Remove `generated` folder form root directory of you magento and then run `setup:di:Compile` and flush `cache`.

**Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
<?php 

namespace Product\SizeChart\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $curdFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Product\SizeChart\Model\ResourceModel\Curd\CollectionFactory $curdFactory
    ) {
        $this->curdFactory = $curdFactory;
    }
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->curdFactory->create();
    }
}
```

> **Must be run Magento upgrade command**

***I Hope This Helps You***